# Track progress of ICO sale

Tags: web3js, javascript

for a client of mine i'm creating a ICO website. The basic html & css code is fully done, and I have implemented a progress bar from Bootstrap on the webpage.

My client asked me if it's possible that this progress bar automatically changes from percentage based on the current available tokens in their ERC20 smart contract address.

I've read some stuff about web3js, but I can't find anything related to this matter.

Is there someone here who is willing to help me with this?

Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

Sure. Just make sure the number you're interested in is available via a public function or variable. I happen to have published a blog post about public variables in Solidity just today: https://programtheblockchain.com/posts/2018/01/02/making-smart-contracts-with-public-variables/.

For example, if you're using the `totalSupply` of an ERC20 token:

```
var abi = ...;  // ABI for your contract, from the Solidity compiler
var address = ...;  // address of the contract
web3.eth.contract(abi).at(address).totalSupply.call(function (err, result) {
  // result here is the total supply of the ERC20 token
});
```